# jQuery doesnt work in custom WordPress template

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm making super simple theme for WordPress, and I've attached jQuery to it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

And it shows in page source. But the thing is, plugins depending on jQuery don't work on my template and in Firebug console I get error `TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function` as if jQuery weren't loaded.

Comment: Did you place your other scripts depending on jQuery after jQuery ?

Comment: I think jQuery was loaded correctly, but flexslider is missing

Comment: Well jquery is loaded from head while flexslider is attached to body via post so it should load after jquery. And flexslider certainly is on page because i can see it in firebug html inspector.

Comment: "attached to body via post" ... if you're loading that library dynamically, the error probably means that some other code is trying to use it before it has been loaded.

Comment: And that would be completely wrong in Wordpress. There's a reason Wordpress has [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [wp_enque_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and the same for styles, it's so you can manage resources in a smart way, with built in dependencies etc. Use them, and note that Wordpress is in no-conflict mode by default so you'll need no-conflict wrappers, and it's all very well documented in the Wordpress Codex.

Comment: i dont know the details how wordpress works, but i dont think that scripts in page body would be run before scripts on head.

Comment: use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: Thing is its the plugin which is attempting to use $ sign not me, can i somehow change it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by inserting jquery-dependent slideshow directly via template (with jquery linked above it in ) instead of by writing post containing shortcode. Perhaps it isnt most elegant solution but time was of the essence.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, WordPress has issues with shorthand jQuery, so instead of $(...) you'd need to use jQuery(...).  If it's the plugin that's trying to use it then you may have to modify the plugin.  Pull the js off the server with FTP and do a simple find/replace (search for "$(" replace with "jQuery(").